# How to make Kdevelop like DockWidget using qt

Tags: kdevelop, qdockwidget

I want to make an IDE but want Kdevelop like dockwidget as shown in figure. I want to use qt. I want to know how this is implemented in Kdevelop. Is it a custom widget using QTabBar and QStackedWidgets or something else?

It would be nice if some one tell me how it is implemented or can be implemented
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Afaik it's `QTabBar` + `QDockWidget` based.

Check the sources, you'll find that in sublime.

This commit added the current implementation:
http://commits.kde.org/kdevplatform/4e204dcafce117f52a9488d6c8a3125d3a21da7e